# Is there a way to change USB Printer URI?

Tags: usb, cups, printer

I'm on Raspbian and I would like to add my USB printer to CUPS. If I try to add the printer, I noticed, that my USB printer is detected as "Unknown" with device URI **usb://Unknown/Printer**.

```
# lpinfo -v
```

returns

```
direct usb://Unknown/Printer
```

lsusb as well as usb-devices return a proper manufacturer and model name.

Where is this device URI coming from? Is there any way to change this device URI to the proper manufacturer and model?